# Group Policy MSI push issue on clients

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm trying to push MSI package through GP and package couldn't be installed due to installation restriction on users PC. I can setup package using my login credentials being part of domain admins. Can someone help and share knowledge "how to" push MSI package with administrative credentials or may be with my username and password. Thanks in advance for assisting

Answer (score 0):

Use a Computer Policy.  Under Computer Configuration, Policies, Software Setting, Software installation, right click and choose New -> Package

Then browse to your .msi

You also need to make sure your .msi is in a share i.e. \server\share